# brew でインストールした jenkins が localhost では接続できないが 127.0.0.1 だと接続できるのはなぜ?

Tags: jenkins

brew でインストールした jenkins があります。

この jenkins は、(ブラウザから) `localhost:8080` でアクセスしても接続できませんが、 `127.0.0.1:8080` ではアクセスが可能です。

localhost は 127.0.0.1 に解決するはずなので、この挙動は何かおかしいと思っています。

#### 質問

- localhost で接続できないけれども、 127.0.0.1 からアクセスできるのは、どうしてなのでしょうか。

Comment: `curl -v http://localhost:8080` などで状況が解るかも知れません。

Comment: このタイトルだと「localhostで接続できない」件は問題無しとも受け取れてしまいますが(知りたいのはあくまで何故IPアドレスなら接続できるのか、だけ？)、この認識であっていますか？もしくは「localhostの指定でも接続できるようにしたい」であるなら、タイトルや本文を見直してもらった方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick 個人的に一番知りたかったのは、「なぜ、 localhost で接続できなかったの説明」なので、その意味で解決済み、と思いアクセプトしている状態です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6が有効な環境であれば、`localhost`は`::1`(IPv6のループバックアドレス)で解決される可能性があります。
そのため、JenkinsがIPv4のみ接続を待ちうけているならば、`localhost`では接続できず、`127.0.0.1`だと接続できる、という事象が生じます。

このあたりを確認してはどうでしょうか?

追記

確認方法の一つとして、`wireshark`等、パケットキャプチャができる環境であれば、「`lo0`」(ループバックインターフェース)をキャプチャすると、「`localhost:8080`」にアクセスした際に「`127.0.0.1`」に向かっているか見えると思います。

OP追記

`curl -v localhost:8080` の結果、 `::1` で解決されているようだ、と確認できました。

Comment: chrome に打ち込んだ localhost が、実際にどう解決されているのか、どうやって確かめたら良いのだろう、と思っています。 nslookup localhost は 127.0.0.1 が返ってきている様子なので。。